# How to replace values that correspond to polygons by NA?

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, r-raster

I have a raster and a shapefile:

```
library(cartography)
library(sf)
library(raster)

r <- raster(matrix(rnorm(10*12), nrow=10), xmn = -180, xmx= 180, ymn = -90, ymx= 90)
mtq <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/mtq.gpkg", package="cartography"), quiet = TRUE)
```

I would like to intersect the raster `r` with the shapefile `mtq` and make the corresponding pixels to the all polygons as NA (replace the values of the pixels in the raster by NA) and return the raster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely looking for `mask`; it lives in both oldish `{raster}` and shiny new `{terra}`.

Note that I had to rewrite your `r` object a bit, as it was not quite compatible with the Martinique vector object from {cartography}.

Edit: if, as seems to be indicated in the comments, you are looking for replacing with NAs the values inside the polygon (and not outside) my answer is still `raster::mask()`, only with a little tweaking of the masking object (you need the inverse of the polygon over the extent of your raster).

```
library(cartography)
library(sf)
library(raster)

mtq <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/mtq.gpkg", package="cartography"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise() # dissolve internal boundaries

r <- raster(matrix(rnorm(10*12), nrow=10), 
            xmn = st_bbox(mtq)["xmin"], 
            xmx= st_bbox(mtq)["xmax"], 
            ymn = st_bbox(mtq)["ymin"], 
            ymx= st_bbox(mtq)["ymax"], 
            crs = st_crs(mtq))

plot(r) # original raster - full extent + range
```

[image]

```
# the masking object:
mask <- st_bbox(r) %>% # take extent of your raster... 
  st_as_sfc() %>% # make it a sf object
  st_set_crs(st_crs(mtq)) %>% # in CRS of your polygon 
  st_difference(mtq) %>% # intersect with the polygon object
  st_as_sf() # interpret as sf (and not sfc) object

result <- r %>% 
  mask(mask)

plot(result)
plot(st_geometry(mtq), add = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what I need to do is to replace those pixels ,in results, by NA in r

Comment: I do need to keep the original extent of the raster.

Comment: raster::mask() keeps the extent and masks the "out" pixels with NA's while raster::crop() reduces the extent of your raster object

Comment: thanks. But here you kept pixels with shapefile? No?